# Is it common to preprocess image data before sending it through a deep net?

Tags: image-classification, preprocessing, object-recognition

I'm curious as how convolutional neural network are used in practice for object recognition. Is it common to perform data preprocessing before providing the data to the input layer ? If so, what types of preprocessing are common ?